# Wygwam for EE3?

Tags: ee3

Are there plans to upgrade Wygwam for the new EE3?  We use this plugin in all our work, so the lack of support for EE3 is a big issue for our firm and we are anxious to move to EE3, but not without Wygwam!

Comment: I don't think Pixel and Tonic has posted their EE3 roadmap yet, but see https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic/status/654257322189950976

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic/status/654257322189950976), it's on it's way! So hopefully sometime in December..?

Personally I'm waiting before jumping onto EE3, I've heard a mixed bag of comments, but heard good things so far regarding EE3.1, so hopefully that's far more solid with all the main snags sorted, it'll also give more time for add-on developers to catchup.

A good list of add-ons being worked on for EE3 [here](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-3-add-on-developer-update-status) and good old [Devot-ee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?&f=ee3) listing those already released.