# EE3 and Playa - do they work together

Tags: playa

I don't see anything in the change log or mentioned on the Pixel and Tonic website.  Does Playa work with ExpressionEngine 3?

Answer (score 2):

Brandon Kelly would definitely list it in a change log if it were released for EE3. I don't think he's actually published a road map for EE3 as of yet, but has tweeted that he is working on EE3-izing his add-ons. You can take a look at EE3 compatible add-ons on the https://www.devot-ee.com. Probably not 100% complete, but it'll be 99% of released EE3 add-ons.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?&f=ee3

Comment: This is correct - Playa has not been unreleased for v3 as yet.

Comment: Do check out EE's revamped relationship functionality as well. Back in the day, Playa was a no-brainer, but recentIy I have not had a case where native EE functionality hadn't served me just as well.

Comment: Second @Ingmar comment, native EE relationship field is an excellent replacement - same for Matrix, the native Grid is just as good. Actually, I only know that Wygwam has been promised for EE3, unknown about Matrix & Playa - see this answer: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/wygwam-for-ee3/34872#34872